# Developing IN an iPod touch

Tags: mobile, ipod-touch

I am thinking about buying an iPod touch and I Wonder if there is Java and c++ editor to install in the iPod, something like having netbeans in the IPod. I want this because I would like to advance in my home-works on my way college-home while I'm on the bus or waiting for someone, etc. Is there anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iTunes App Store restrictions explicitly prohibit any compilers or interpreters from running on approved iOS apps.

That said, you could make a simple Javascript interpreter in a webpage, and then save it for offline use, without much trouble.

For that matter, any language that's implemented in Javascript and can work in an offline webpage could be used.  For example, if you had a compiler written in Javascript, which compiled C++ to Javascript, then you could use that to write C++ on your iPod.  I do not know of any such compilers offhand, but there's no theoretical reason they couldn't exist, as the App Store restrictions don't apply to HTML pages you browse to yourself.

A far more practical solution would be to just get a text editor (of which the App Store has many).  Write your code on the bus, and then compile it when you get home.  It will still be faster than the compilers we had when I was a kid!

(Or just get an SRS and spend the time studying rather than programming, since you're not going to be very effective at programming on a small touchscreen device, anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't even consider trying to write code on an iPod, or even an iPad.

iPod is the wrong type of device for any sort of development.  There are some ergonomic factors which are really important when it comes to writing code:

1. You should have a decent keyboard - i-devices only have touch-screens.  A laptop keyboard is OK but not great.
2. You need the screen at a reasonable height and angle if you're going to be looking at it for a long time.  You need to be able to type with both hands at the same time.
3. You need as much screen space as you can get.

I could come up with a lot more reasons for not using an i-device for development, but I think they are too obvious to bother listing.

If you really want to do your homework on the bus, you are better off getting yourself a decent laptop.

Comment: @Roger - same issues.  Use a laptop :)

Answer (score 1):

There's always an option to jailbreak your device and install GCC toolchain: [iphone-gcc](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/iphone-gcc) in Cydia and instruction [here](http://www.hackint0sh.org/f9/44218.htm). Netbook would be a much better option though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some basic HTML and Latex but no Java or C++.
But I found something that could be interesting:

Processing is quite like Java and can be programmed on this site, with every iDevice.
http://jepstone.net/HiperPad/editor.php/HiPad4d113f1595b4c#home